# GFCI connected with 2-black wires (both hot) and 2-white wires. Connected to line and load. GFCI does not work

Tags: gfci

C/B connected to both bathrooms’ outlets. GFCI not working. Tried to replace, but line and load connections are both incoming hot wires, even when disconnected from GFCI. How do I get this to work properly?

Comment: Can you post a picture looking into the box please?  And also, what else does this circuit serve?  Because it's possible one of those two hots was supposed to be the load, supplied from this GFCI, but it got shorted to another hot somewhere else in the circuit.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please? What are you using to test wires for hot-ness?